# Alert Admins when changes are made?

Tags: wordpress, contacts, civirules

If someone with access to the Civi dashboard makes a change to any contact information, is there a way to send an email alert to the site Administrators?

Civi 5.2 
WordPress 4.9

***ADDITIONAL INFO ADDED 11/30 ****

I am experimenting with CiviRules.  It looks promising, but I still haven't found a solution.  I am going to spell out more what I am trying to do and hopefully someone can clarify if Civirules can achieve that.

We have about 60 volunteers sorted in a group.  Occasionally a member of the staff will make a change to a volunteers contact information.  The Coordinator who oversees this group of volunteers wants to receive an email alert anytime a change is made to any contact within that group.

It looks like we might be able to do that with CiviRules, but I am not yet seeing how to apply a rule to a specific group and how to get it to email a specific person when a change is made to that group.
I have the Linked Trigger set to "contact of any type is changed"
I am not seeing anything that sounds like it fits in Linked Conditions or Linked Action, such as email this coordinator when a change is made.
I guess I am still not understanding how it works.

Comment: have you looked at civirules?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand completely what you want to achieve, but if you want to send an email to checks@example.org every time a contact in group Special changes here is what you would have to do:

- install the Email API action (https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api) which will also add the CiviRule action *Send Email*
- add a new Rule with trigger *Contact of Any Type is Changed*
- add condition *Contact is in Group* and select group Special
- add an action *Send Email* and add email address checks@example.org

Comment: That does sound like what I am trying to do. I am try that as soon as I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

That could be a lot of alerts!  You could write something using [hook_civicrm_pre](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_pre/) or hook_civicrm_post.  It might be more practical to create a report for an admin's dashboard than send a mail on every change.

Comment: I see how to create the report and have it send daily, weekly or monthly.  How can I get it to send after every change?

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use the CiviRules extension (https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules)( to achieve that? There is also documentation for the extension at https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/.

Comment: thank you.  Additional information is added to my post.

Answer (score 0):

> Occasionally a member of the staff will make a change to a volunteers contact information.

How about that make that change via a Profile and then you can set the Profile settings to notify someone, ie do this instead of having the changes made directly on the Contact Summary screen. I think that logic would get what you want, but understand it could be hard to get they 'staff' to remember to only change certain records via a Profile

Comment: will also depend what sort of information is being changed

Comment: I like that idea and it would be simply.  Unfortunately the staff will be browsing the profiles from the dashboard though.  They will doing  all the editing back there.